# scipy.optimize.minimize results differ between Python 2.x-3.x

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

Basically, I have a nonlinear constrained problem using the SLSQP solver in scipy.optimize.minimize. Unfortunately, the problem (same file, same code) is returning different results on different computers (one Windows, one Linux). The scipy version is the same (1.2.1). Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

class OptimalAcc():
    def __init__(self, v0, tg, tr, D0, sgr, l, t0, a0, b0, 
                       rho_t=0.5, rho_u=0.5, vM=15, vm=2.78, aM=2.5, am=-2.9):

        # Problem constants
        self.v0 = v0
        self.D0 = D0
        self.sgr = sgr
        self.l = l
        self.T = tg + tr
        self.D = tg / self.T
        self.t0 = t0
        self.a0 = a0
        self.b0 = b0        
        self.rho_t = rho_t
        self.rho_u = rho_u
        self.vM = vM
        self.vm = vm
        self.aM = aM
        self.am = am

    def cost_fn(self, x):

        # Acceleration profile variables
        t = x[:1]
        a = x[1:2]
        b = x[2:3]

        # Objective function
        f = self.rho_t*x[:1]+self.rho_u*(a**2*t**3/3 +
                                         a*b*t**2 +
                                         b**2*t)
        return f

    def solve(self):

        # Inequality constraints
        ineq = ({'type':'ineq',
             'fun':lambda x: np.array([self.aM - x[2],
                                       x[2]-self.am,
                                       x[0],
                                       self.vM - (self.v0 + x[2]*x[0] + 0.5*x[1]*x[0]**2),
                                       self.v0 + x[2]*x[0] + 0.5*x[1]*x[0]**2 - self.vm,
                                       np.sin(np.pi*self.D - np.pi/2)-
                                       np.sin(2*np.pi*(x[0] -((self.D0*self.T)/abs(self.sgr-2)))/self.T + 3*np.pi/2 - np.pi*self.D)])})

        # Equality constraints
        eq = ({'type':'eq',
               'fun':lambda x: np.array([x[1]*x[0] + x[2],
                                         self.v0*x[0] + 0.5*x[2]*x[0]**2 + x[1]*x[0]**3/6 - self.l])})

        # Starting points
        x0 = np.array([self.t0, self.a0, self.b0])

        # Solve optimization problem
        res = minimize(self.cost_fn, 
                       x0=x0,
                       constraints=[ineq,eq],
                       options={'disp': True})

        return res

if __name__== "__main__":
    v0 = 1
    tg = 20
    tr = 20
    D0 = 1
    sgr = 1
    l = 70
    t0 = 10
    a0 = -0.1
    b0 = 1.5

    # Create instance of optimization problem class
    obj = OptimalAcc(v0, tg, tr, D0, sgr, l, t0, a0, b0)

    # Solve problem and return optimal profile
    u_t = obj.solve().x
    print('x_1:',u_t[0])
    print('x_2:',u_t[1])
    print('x_3:',u_t[2])
```

The Windows machine yields:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 8.696191258640086
            Iterations: 7
            Function evaluations: 35
            Gradient evaluations: 7
x_1: 13.508645429307041
x_2: -0.06874922875473621
x_3: 0.9287089606820067
```

I believe these results are locally optimal and I can verify the same output with fmincon in MATLAB.

However, the Linux machine yields:

```
Positive directional derivative for linesearch    (Exit mode 8)
            Current function value: 14.4116342889
            Iterations: 17
            Function evaluations: 147
            Gradient evaluations: 13
x_1: 7.65875894797259
x_2: -0.241800477348664
x_3: 2.5000000000000053
```

Clearly, the optimizer is getting stuck in the Linux computer. What could be causing this? My only guess is that there's some precision within numpy that's throwing off the numbers.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the result; running it on Ubuntu 18.04 gives me the same results as you report for windows (running scipy `1.1.0` and numpy `1.15.1`). Which python version are you using?

Comment: The Linux computer is running 2.7, Windows is 3.6.  But I'm assuming Python is not the culprit here?

Comment: Ah, this might be it, actually. In Python 2, `a**2*t**3/3` could cause an issue if all of the values are integers i.e. all fractions where you use integers instead of floats. Could you add a `from __future__ import division` at the top and see whether that solves the issue?

Comment: You're right! I don't have access to the Linux machine now but I replicated everything on a Linux VM on my Windows computer and got both results, after adding `from __future__ import division`. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This is a lesson in debugging: machine A is Linux/ Python 2.7, B is Win/ Python 3.6. Simply state those facts, don't jump to the assumption it must be the OSes. Also, compare apples-to-apples: run it on both 3.6 on platforms(!). Also, by now there are tons of migration guides/ testing practices on 2-to-3 migration, read them and write some testcases.

Comment: I edited your title to remove the assumption that it must be the OSes. and in fact it's not even `scipy.optimize.minimize` either, it's simply a Python 2.x-3.x difference in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the issue is most likely not related to Windows vs. Linux, but more a Python 2 vs. Python 3 one. For example, the term

```
a**2*t**3/3
```

can look different between Python 2 and 3 as there might be only integers involved (there are more examples like this in your code).

An easy fix might be to include

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the top of your script which would take care of the differences on how divisions are performed in Python 2 and 3.